# Why does a method with the same type argument with "const" at the end give an ERROR 0308?

Tags: c++

code:

```
class InArgClass
{
    InArgClass(int In) { }
};

class ToolClass
{
public:
    void TestFunc(const InArgClass& Name) { }

    void TestFunc(int index) const { } // E0308
    //void TestFunc(int index) { }; // NO ERROR
};

int main()
{
    //std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    ToolClass* m = new ToolClass();
    m->TestFunc(100);
}
```

The class has a method with int argument, so in "const" at end of function int and InArgClass equal?

ERROR 0308: more than one instance of overloaded function

Comment: The class does not have any kind of a constructor.

Comment: `InArgClass` can be implicitly constructed from an `int`. Try making your `InArgClass` constructor `explicit`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The question doesn't express its intent well, but it is asking about the ambiguity of the call due to the constructor of `InArgClass`. It refers to that constructor.

Comment: Just to clarify: actually `InArgClass` **cannot** be implicitly constructed from an `int` because its constructor is private. Still, I believe the error is issued before the compiler checks for the visibility of member functions.

Comment: No idea why that question has been closed! It is quite clear that author asked *why* an additional const results in the given error. Also the error message is present! The misleading wording of the headline was already replaced. So please leave the question open as it is absolutely valid to ask for this topic ( if we did not find a dup or something else ) PLEASE REOPEN!

Comment: I don't think the question should be closed. It could definitively be improved, but the intent seems clear to me: "Why does adding `const` in the code make the call ambiguous?"

Comment: @paolo Correct, se for instance https://godbolt.org/z/56vhqMhh8. It is the const conversion (of this:ToolClass) vs. the implicit int to InArgClass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, here you are the problem. `InArgClass` defines a (private) constructor from an `int` which is not marked `explicit`.

When you try to call `m->TestFunc(100)`, the compiler has to decide whether:

1. To promote `m` (which is non-`const`) to `const` and call the `int` overload (gcc issues a warning but does that);
2. To try and construct a temporary `InArgClass` instance from `100` and call the `InArgClass const&` overload (it will later realize that it cannot as the constructor is private).

There are at least 3 ways to make that call non ambiguous:

1. Mark the constructor as explicit

```cpp
class InArgClass
{
    explicit InArgClass(int In) { }
};
```

2. Mark the first overload as `const` (if possible)

```cpp
void TestFunc(const InArgClass& Name) const { }
```

3. Make `m` a `ToolClass const*`:

```cpp
ToolClass const* m = new ToolClass();
```

Comment: "_gcc issues a warning but does that_": Why would there be a warning? A non-`const` lvalue can bind to a `const` lvalue reference. This is also not a promotion (or a conversion), just reference-binding.

Comment: The warning says the call is ambiguous, as per ISO C++: `warning: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second`. It will turn into an error if you compile with `-Wpedantic`.

Comment: @user17732522 When i first tested the given snippet, i did get a warning. [Live warning demo](https://onlinegdb.com/RZE33DPZ5q).

Comment: (also @AnoopRana) Ah, so the warning is not for the `const` binding/conversion, but for the whole overload resolution being ambiguous. Yes, that is just GCC extending the rules to make the overload resolution that would be ill-formed according to the standard work. If you want portable code at all, this shouldn't be relied upon.

Comment: @user17732522 Yes. I posted the link just cuz in your first comment you were asking *"why there would be a warning"*. Agreed that this shouldn't be relied upon.

Comment: @AnoopRana Yes, my bad. I wasn't aware GCC allowed that. I should have tested it first.

Answer (score 4):

The problem appears because the overload resolution considers whether implicit conversions needs to be applied.

No conversions is of course being the preferred.

So in your example

```
ToolClass* m = new ToolClass();
m->TestFunc(100)
```

It sees a to *const* conversion, and a conversion via the int constructor of InArgClass.

These conversions has the same cost, so the compiler says it is ambiguous.

So if you for instance change this to

```
const ToolClass* m = new ToolClass();
m->TestFunc(100);
```

There is no longer a const conversion. So the const version of TestFunc() is the no-conversion form, and will be selected.

And the [NO ERROR] version also is a no-conversion alternative.

And finally, as @paolo noted, this resolution is done before visibility considerations (for good reason).

Comment: For me it is quite interesting that making the constructor public will not solve the issue. Making the object const is invalid, but access the now public constructor would be valid. That this will not reduce the "cost" is interesting... If I read https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution I simply overstrained :-)

Comment: A `const` conversion (although technically here it is only reference-binding, not a conversion) is considered better than a user-defined conversion via the constructor. But these act on two different argument/parameter pairs here, so it doesn't matter what relative ranking these conversions have.

Answer (score 0):

##### Case 1

Here we consider the case where we have the following 2 member functions:

```
void TestFunc(const InArgClass& Name) { }

void TestFunc(int index) const { } //ERROR
```

Now, for the call expression `m->TestFunc(100);`, during overload resolution both of the above shown member functions are treatd as if they have an *implicit object parameter*. In case of the member function `ToolClass::TestFunc(const InArgClass&)` the implicit object parameter has type `ToolClass&`. While the 2nd member function `ToolClass::TestFunc(int index) const` has an implicit object parameter of type `const ToolClass&` during overload resolution.

Now for the call expression, `m->TestFunc(100)`, both of the above mentioned member functions are **viable**.

But note that since `m` point to a `non-const` `ToolClass` object and so for the 1st member function there is no need for any conversion for the first argument(since the implicit object parameter is of type `ToolClass&`) but an implicit conversion is needed for the second argument from `int` to `const InArgClass` type object.

On the other hand, in case of the second member function, since the implicit object parameter is of type `const ToolClass&`, so a conversion is needed for the first passed argument. But no conversion is needed for the second passed argument.

Thus, both of these member functions are equally ranked(meaning they are equally worse). And hence the mentioned ambiguous error.

##### Case 2

Here we consider the case where we've the following 2 member functions:

```
void TestFunc(const InArgClass& Name) { }
void TestFunc(int index) { };
```

In this case the second member function `ToolClass::TestFunc(int index)` is treated as if it has an implicit object parameter of type `ToolClass&` during overloaded resolution.

This means that this time, for the call expression `m->TestFunc(100)`  there is no implicit conversion needed for the first passed argument to the implicit object parameter since the object on which the member function was called is essentially a non-const `ToolClass` and the implied object parameter has the type `ToolClass&` instead of `const ToolClass&`. Thus, this time the 2nd member function is a **better match** than the first member function as for the first member function there is need for an implicit conversion of the second passed `int` argument. So, the second member function is a better match than the first member function in this case and hence this compiles fine.

---

One way to solve this(the error in case 1) is to make the **converting ctor** inside class `InArgClass` **explicit** as shown below:

```
class InArgClass
{
   explicit InArgClass(int In) { }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

When overload resolution is performed against the two overloads of the member function, they are considered to have an additional parameter, called the *implicit object parameter*. The argument to this parameter is the object expression (here `*m`).

For a `const`-qualified member function, since it should be callable also with a `const`-qualified object expression, the implicit object parameter will have type `const ToolClass&`.

If the function is not `const`-qualified, then it will be `ToolClass&` instead, since it shouldn't be callable on a `const` glvalue.

So, essentially the two function's parameter lists against which overload resolution is performed are

```
TestFunc(ToolClass&, const InArgClass& Name)
TestFunc(const ToolClass&, int Name)
```

and the arguments are a non-`const` `ToolClass` lvalue (`*m`) and an `int` prvalue (`100`).

Both functions are viable: Both `ToolClass&` and `const ToolClass&` can bind directly to a non-`const` lvalue of type `ToolClass`. `100` can be passed in the second overload without conversion and in the first overload with a user-defined conversion to `InArgClass` using its converting (non-`explicit`) constructor and the `const` lvalue reference parameter can bind to the resulting temporary. That constructor is `private`, so not accessible in the context, but overload resolution does not consider accessibility. It would be checked later if that overload were to be chosen.

The conversion from `int` to `InArgClass` is clearly worse than the identity conversion from `int` to `int`. So the second overload would be preferred based on the second argument/parameter pair.

However, for the first argument, binding to a `const` lvalue reference is considered better than binding to a non-`const` lvalue reference. So based on the first argument/parameter pair, the first overload should be preferred.

If two argument/parameter pairs disagree on being a better overload in this way, then neither function is considered better than the other and since there is no third overload to consider, the whole overload resolution will end up ambiguous.

Without `const` on the second overload, the first parameter/argument pair will not make either overload better than the other, but since the second pair is a better match for the second overload, the second overload will be chosen in the end.